# Reset multiple form elements using .reset()

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the right way to reset multiple form elements when using .rest()?

This one below, works for one, but how is it if I needed to do it for more than one?

```
$("#client")[0].reset(); // Works for one
$("#client")[0][1].reset(); // For multiple, but does not work.
```

Other than doing:

```
$("#client")[0].reset();
$("#client")[1].reset();
$("#client")[2].reset();
```

Comment: Is client the ID of your form? And do you want to reset the WHOLE form, or just specific options?

Comment: @RUJordan Right, It's the ID of the form. I'm trying to reset elements 0, 2, 5

Comment: `$("#client").find('input').get(1).reset();`

Comment: $("#client").trigger('reset');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give all element to class like

```
class="name1"
```

And then use in jquery as

```
$(".name1").reset();
```

Comment: Somehow, this does not work for me. My form id is #client and the first field which is a textarea is .name

Comment: What about this `$("#client").trigger('reset');`

Comment: try this `$(".name").val("");`

Comment: $("#client").trigger('reset'); Works well at resetting the entire form. Any way I can tell it to target .name and .password and .location?

Comment: U can use `$(".name,.password,.location).val("");`